# java script array assignation mistake

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var UserBoard = new Array(20,20);
for(var i = 0; i < 21; ++i){
    for(var j = 0; j < 21; ++j){
        UserBoard[i,j] = 0;
    }
}
document.write(UserBoard[3,5]);
UserBoard[4,5]=1;
document.write(UserBoard[3,5]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XbyqN/2/

it's quite simple but I don't know why does this. Alert should be 0, not 1 since I've initialized the 2d array to 0.

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: I dont think multi dimensional arrays work like this... `[i]=[]` in the first loop.. [i][j]=0 in the second

Comment: When you have just a small javascript code, no css, no html, it's perfectly fine to put it in the question, so that we don't have to look at the fiddle and we're sure it remains available for future users.

Comment: just another quick tip: instead of hard coding the max value of `i` or `j` in your for loops, use `theArray.length`, because in your fiddle, the loops are adding an extra index to the array: arrays are 0 indexed, like most languages, so an array of length 20 has 19 as highest index, not 20.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's break it down

```
var UserBoard = new Array(20,20);
```

You are creating an array with two slots, both of them containing the value "20" (int). So your array is `[20, 20]`

Next, your loop :

```
for(var i = 0; i < 21; ++i){
  for(var j = 0; j < 21; ++j){
    UserBoard[i,j] = 0;
  }
}
```

Two dimensional arrays are not defined like this. In that case, only the "j" counter does something. The "i" is simply ignored. So you end up with an array as follow : `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Next, the assignement :

```
UserBoard[4,5]=1;
```

Is equivalent to :

```
UserBoard[5]=1;
```

And your alert :

```
alert("test: " + UserBoard[3,5]);
```

Is equivalent to :

```
alert("test: " + UserBoard[5]);
```

That's why you get "1" as alert.

If you want two dimensional arrays, you should use the following notation :

```
UserBoard[4][5] = 1;
```

Read it all here on MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 1):

You want `UserBoard[i][j]` instead of `UserBoard[i,j]`.

Multidimensional arrays don't work as you seem to think they work. They're, in fact, arrays of arrays.

Use this :

```
var UserBoard = new Array(20);
for(var i = 0; i < 20; ++i){
  UserBoard[i] = new Array(20);
  for(var j = 0; j < 20; ++j){
    UserBoard[i][j] = 0;
  }
}
```

I suggest you start using `console.log` and Chrome's developer tool to debug your code (or Firebug). Try this at the end of your code and then type the F12 key :

```
console.log(UserBoard);
```

Answer (score 1):

The comma operator evaluates both of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the second operand.

```
var UserBoard = new Array(20,20); // [20, 20]
for(var i = 0; i < 21; ++i){
  for(var j = 0; j < 21; ++j){
    UserBoard[i,j] = 0; // UserBoard[j] = 0
  }
}
UserBoard[4,5]=1; // UserBoard[5] = 1
alert("test: " + UserBoard[3,5]); // UserBoard[5]
```

What you want is:

```
var UserBoard = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) { // i < 20
    UserBoard[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        UserBoard[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
UserBoard[4][5]=1;
alert("test: " + UserBoard[3][5]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new array using the array constructor (`new Array`), the arguments have different meanings, depending on the type and total number of arguments.

```
var array20long = new Array(20);// = [undefined,undefined,undefined,....].length === 20
var arrayString = new Array('foo');// = ['foo']
var yourArray = new Array(20,20);// = [20,20]
```

Put simply: passing 1 integer to the array constructor, creates an array with length equal to the int passed, passing several integers will result in 1, 1 dimensional array with a length equal to the total number of argumens. In your case, two integers creating an array with 2 values. Each index will be initialized to its corresponding argument. In your case: index 0 === 20, index 1 === 20, if you had written `new Array(20,10)`, the result would be an array like `[20,10]`.

You get the basic idea.
It is important to note that accessing multi dimensional arrays using a comma won't work: instead of writing `arr[1,2]` you should have written `arr[1][2]`. Google some introductory tutorials to JavaScript, it won't hurt... and you'll soon learn why using the array constructor isn't the best way of creating arrays